# Prove that this is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $K$ be a field and $p(x)\in K[x]$ an irreducible polynomial with $\deg p=n>1$.

In $K[x]$ we define the following relation: $$f(x)\equiv g(x) \Leftrightarrow p(x)\mid (f(x)-g(x))$$

I want to prove that this is an equivalence relation.

I have done the following:

- $f(x)\equiv f(x) \Leftrightarrow p(x)\mid (f(x)-f(x)) \Leftrightarrow p(x)\mid 0  \ \ \checkmark$
- When $f(x)\equiv g(x) \Leftrightarrow p(x)\mid (f(x)-g(x))$ then we have also that $p(x)\mid (g(x)-f(x)) \Leftrightarrow g(x)\equiv f(x)$
- When $f(x)\equiv g(x) \Leftrightarrow p(x)\mid (f(x)-g(x)) \\ \Rightarrow f(x)-g(x)=r_1(x)p(x) \Rightarrow g(x)=f(x)+r_1(x)p(x)$

  and $g(x)\equiv h(x) \Leftrightarrow p(x)\mid (g(x)-h(x))\Rightarrow g(x)-h(x)=r_2(x)p(x) $

  then we have that $f(x)+r_1(x)p(x)-h(x)=r_2(x)p(x) \Rightarrow f(x)-h(x)=(r_2(x)-r_1(x))p(x) \\ \Rightarrow p(x)\mid (f(x)-h(x))$

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks good.

Comment: Do it first with the ring of the integers instead of $K[x]$, and with $p$ being a prime number, instead of a polynomial.  Also, it will be helpful to examine the factor ring of your original ring by the prime ideal generated by $p$.

Comment: Note that you do not need that $p$ is irreducible or  any specific property of the ring $K[x]$.

Comment: You could also use $f(x)-h(x) = f(x)-g(x)+g(x)-h(x) = (f(x)-g(x)) + (g(x)-h(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems good, but I don't like at all the style. Your use of $\Leftrightarrow$ is disputable.

**Reflexivity** Let $f(x)\in K[x]$; since $f(x)-f(x)=0$ and $p(x)\mid 0$, we have that $f(x)\equiv f(x)$.

**Symmetry** Assume $f(x)\equiv g(x)$. Then $p(x)\mid (f(x)-g(x))$ so $f(x)-g(x)=r(x)p(x)$ for some $r(x)\in K[x]$. Therefore $g(x)-f(x)=-r(x)p(x)$ and so $g(x)\equiv f(x)$.

**Transitivity** Assume $f(x)\equiv g(x)$ and $g(x)\equiv h(x)$. Then $f(x)-g(x)=r_1(x)p(x)$ and $g(x)-h(x)=r_2(x)p(x)$ so that
$$
f(x)-h(x)=r_1(x)p(x)+r_2(x)p(x)=(r_1(x)+r_2(x))p(x)
$$
hence $f(x)\equiv h(x)$.

---

As an aside, the proof is exactly the same if you consider $R$ any commutative ring, $p\in R$ and define $a\equiv b$ if and only if $p\mid(a-b)$ (that is, $a-b=rp$ for some $r\in R$).

The condition is exactly the same as saying $a-b\in (p)$ (the principal ideal generated by $p$). More generally, if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, the relation $a\equiv b$ if and only if $a-b\in I$ is an equivalence relation.

The assumptions that $p(x)$ has degree $n>1$ and that it is irreducible are completely redundant.